# Will this circuit fuse blow? - Exam Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I was surprised by this question in my physics exam. The question seems flawed to me:

**Stephen has designed a lighting circuit which includes a 48 Ω resistor. Calculate the number of 100W globes that can be used in series across 240V simultaneously before overloading the circuit and blowing the fuse.**

The correct answer was as follows:

```
Find the total current of the circuit:
I (total) = V / R
          = 240V / 48Ω
          = 5A

Find current of single globe:
I = P / V
I = 100W / 240V
I = 0.417A

Find maximum number of globes:
Number of globes = 5 / 0.417 (Total current / current through single globe)
                 = 11.99
∴ The circuit can support 11 globes before the fuse blows
```

Would I be correct in saying the problem lies with the calculation of total current? The total current should equal the total voltage divided by total resistance, however the calculation does not account for the globes in series and only for the 48Ω resistor. Another problem that seems apparent to me is no reference to what current the fuse can support. Am I correct in saying that total current changes based on how many globes are in series, and that it is no reference what so ever to when the fuse will blow?

My teacher has assured me this answer is correct, however I'm still confused by the concept.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The bulbs are in "series" but the solutions  adds the currents, so they are being treated as in   parallel. Then there is  no explanation of where of what rating the fuse has. You are correct in that this question is nonsensical. What was teacher thinking? Did he create the question?

Comment: @mikestone thanks for confirming this. There was another solution in which the total power of the circuit was calculated using V^2/R, and similarly compared to the individual power of each globe (same answer achieved). However it appears just as nonsensical to me.

Comment: Furthermore, adding bulbs would increase the resistance; adding more bulbs in series is reducing the current and so moving away from blowing the fuse. I suggest you move this question to EE too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'solution' makes essentially zero sense. Indeed, it's of the *not even wrong* variety.

(0) A resistor is only a 'fuse' in the sense that it will overheat and perhaps smoke before opening up if the power dissipated is well above the power rating for some time. But there's no mention of the power rating of this resistor 'fuse' so there's not enough information given to even make a guess at what current would cause it to open up.

(1) The calculation for the 5A maximum current calculation assumes the full 240V is *dropped* across the 48 ohm resistor 'fuse'. Why? Consider that it could only be a 'fuse' if it's in series with the load (a fuse protects a circuit by becoming an open circuit). But if it's in series with the load, it would have the full 240V across only if the load has *zero* volts across. But globes with zero volts across have *zero* current through! The 5A current calculation makes zero sense in this context.

(2) The calculation for the current through a single globe assumes the entire 240V is across the globe. But, if there's a 48 ohm resistor 'fuse' in series, the globe current is through that resistor which means that the voltage across the globe is *less* than 240V. Which means the calculated current isn't relevant to this problem.

(3) The problem statement mentions that the globes are in series but clearly, only when the globes are parallel connected do we add their currents.

Answer (score 0):

The teacher is wrong. Not even wrong. In a very embarrassing way.

You should complain to his supervisor if he is not willing to accept his mistake.